# $\hat{L^p}\subseteq L^p$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Can anyone give me some references to prove this statement that I found in

*Hyakuna, Ryosuke; Tsutsumi, Masayoshi*, [**On existence of global solutions of Schrödinger equations with subcritical nonlinearity for (\widehat L^p)-initial data**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-2012-11314-0), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 140, No. 11, 3905-3920 (2012). [ZBL1283.35126](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1283.35126).`:

Given
$$\hat {L^p}:=\{ \phi: \hat{\phi} \in L^{p'} \}$$ if $p\geq2$

$$\hat{L^p} \subseteq L^p$$
Authors only said it is due to the Hausdorff-Young inequality but in my opinion this inequality can be used only for the proof of $$L^p \subseteq \hat{L^p}, \quad \text{if} \quad  p<2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two inequalities are equivalent by the Fourier inversion theorem. Indeed, if $f∈ L^p$ with $p≥ 2$, then $p'≤2$ and so defining $g = \mathcal F^{-1}(f)$ the inverse Fourier transform of $f$, by what you call Hausdorf-Young's inequality, it holds
$$
\|f\|_{L^p} = \|\widehat g\|_{L^p} ≤ \|g\|_{L^{p'}} = \|\widehat f\|_{L^{p'}}.
$$
which gives you your first inclusion.

Comment: But $g= \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)$ (you wrote $g= \hat{f}$. Of course I am missing something..can you help?

Comment: No, I wrote the equality for the norms. One has (perhaps with a constant depending on your definition of the Fourier transform):
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(x) = \mathcal{F}(f)(-x) = \overline{\mathcal{F}(f)(x)}
$$
and so
$$
\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)\|_{L^p} = \|\mathcal{F}(f)\|_{L^p}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers and availability!